# Fixed Header Scrolling Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating a fixed nav so when the user scrolls and hits the top of the nav the nav is position:fixed to the top of the screen.

It's more a query than anything else because when the variable 'navOffset' is inside the scroll function the header jitters, but when outside the function it works smoothly.

The class 'fixed' which gets added kept getting added and removed when inside.

Is this because it doesn't have anything time to calculate the offset or something? I couldn't work out why.

Cheers

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
        <style media="screen">
            html, body {
                padding: 0;
                margin: 0;
                color: #fff;
            }
            * {
                box-sizing: border-box;
            }
            .pd {
                padding: 8rem;
            }
            .header {
                background: orangered;
            }
            .section-a {
                background: steelblue;
            }
            .section-b {
                background: orange;
            }
            .section-c {
                background: purple
            }
            .section-d {
                background: black;
            }
            footer {
                background: red;
            }

            nav {
                background: #333;
                color: #fff;
                padding: 3rem 0;
                text-align: center;
            }

            nav ul {
                display: inline-block;
            }

            nav li {
                display: inline-block;
                padding-right: 5px;
            }

            .fixed {
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                width: 100%;
                position: fixed;
                z-index: 10000;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="header pd">
            <h1>Header</h1>
        </div>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li>Section A</li>
                <li>Section B</li>
                <li>Section C</li>
                <li>Section D</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <div class="section-a pd">
            <h3>Section A</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="section-b pd">
            <h3>Section B</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="section-c pd">
            <h3>Section C</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="section-d pd">
            <h3>Section D</h3>
        </div>
    </body>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    (function(){

        $(document).on("scroll", function(){
            var navOffset = $("nav").offset();
            var scrollTop = $(document).scrollTop();

            if(scrollTop > navOffset.top) {
                console.log(scrollTop);
                $("nav").addClass("fixed");
            } else {
                $("nav").removeClass("fixed");
            }
        });
    }());
    </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. I changed var navOffset = $("nav").position();

```css
(function(){

        $(document).on("scroll", function(){
            var navOffset = $("nav").position();
            var scrollTop = $(document).scrollTop();
console.log(navOffset)
            if(scrollTop > navOffset.top) {
                console.log(scrollTop);
                $("nav").addClass("fixed");
            } else {
                $("nav").removeClass("fixed");
            }
        });
    }());
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are only checking for when the `scrollTop` is *greater than* the `navOffset.top`.  However, when it is appropriately fixed, they will *be the same*.  As such, just change the evaluation to greater than *or equal*  ==> `if(scrollTop >= navOffset.top {`).